# How can one create a unique label for each macro call using mips assembly in MPLAB X

Tags: assembly, mips, mplab, pic32

I have a macro which performs a comparison, and jumps to the end of the macro if that comparison isn't true. Here is a simplified example:

```
.macro do_work_if_value_not_zero value
    li s0, value
    bne s0, zero, exit_label
    nop   

    // Do work

    exit_label:
.endm
```

The issue however is that I call this macro several times like so:

```
do_work_if_value_not_zero 5
do_work_if_value_not_zero 3
do_work_if_value_not_zero 12
```

As a result I receive the following error:

> Error: symbol `exit_label' is already defined

Because I never call the macro with the same parameter multiple times, I attempted to use the parameter name concatenated with a ':' to create a unique label like so:

```
.macro do_work_if_value_not_zero value
    li s0, value
    bne s0, zero, \value
    nop   

    // Do work

    \value:
.endm
```

However this did not seem to work, and I received more errors.

Thus my question is, how can one create a unique exit label for each macro call to avoid this issue?

Comment: what if you did `\value :` (note the whitespace).  I don't have an environment set up to test this, but this link gave me the idea: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html#Macro

Comment: Thank you for the comment, unfortunately adding the whitespace resulted in the same problem: It works for one call to the macro, but not multiple =/

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like you making a label out of it when you are also using it as a value.  Try passing in a second parameter to your macro that will be used purely for the label.

Comment: Ahh nice this works! I also realized why your other suggestion didn't work: since value is a number, we can't use it as a label name because its' value isn't a proper line number we can jump to (I think). The solution was to concatenate some text before it to make it a good label name. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most assemblers allow local labels like this:

```
.macro do_work_if_value_not_zero 
    li s0, value
    bne s0, zero, 1f     # 1f means branch forward to the next label '1:'
    nop   

    // Do work

    1:
.endm
```

From the MIPS assembler manual [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse410/07sp/misc/MIPS-ASM-007-2418-006.pdf):

> A generated label is a single numeric value (1...255). To reference a
>   generated label, put an f (forward) or a b (backward) immediately
>   after the digit. The reference tells the assembler to look for the
>   nearest generated label that corresponds to the number in the
>   lexically forward or backward direction.

Answer (score 0):

@markgz's answer is the best one

I will keep this answer up in case an alternative solution is needed

---

The issue here is that `value` can't be used as a label as it is a number. As such, it likely doesn't contain the line number that we would like to jump to.

There are two solutions to this problem.

**First**

We can concatenate text to `value` in order to make it a proper label name like so

```
exitLabel\value :
```

**Second** (Courtesy of @Christian Gibbons)

We can add another parameter to specify the label name like so

```
.macro do_work_if_value_not_zero value exitLabelName
    ...
    ...
\exitLabelName :
```

This solution means that one can call the macro with the same parameters multiple times unlike the first solution which is limited to only unique calls to the macro.